# Text in quote style with caption

Tags: captions, quoting

I need to put a output of a program in a quote stile but i need to put a `\caption` tag like an image or a table.

I need to do something like:

text
other text
...
Output X: something

What i can do this?

Edit 1:

I have a multiline quote like this:

```
\begin{quote}
    {\bf Percorso del dataset:} Utile in caso di approccio \ac{MC} per individuare il dataset con le epoche random che ha portato allo score migliore;\\
    {\bf Numero totale di epoche:} Utile nel caso 3 per specificare qual'è il numero di epoche che portato allo score migliore; \\
    {\bf Istanti di transizione da un epoca all'altra:} Utile in caso di approccio \ac{MC} per caratterizzare la sequenza di epoche appresa che ha portato allo score migliore; \\
    {\bf Score globale:} Score dell'intera sequenza di strutture; \\
    {\bf Lista dei NaN:} Eventuale lista degli score con valore \ac{NaN};
\end{quote}
```

I need to put a label "Quote X: blablabla" at the bottom of the quote. I don't like the figure tag, because it isn't a figure.

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable (minimum working) example with a snippet of some code to your post by editing it? We are guessing right now, it would help the solvers a lot.

Comment: @Neptune: What is the `\ac` command?

Comment: (A little off-topic) Did you tried the [Dialogue package](http://ctan.org/pkg/dialogue) to typeset dialogues? It will spare you those `{\bf ... }.

Answer (score 4):

One can create a new float type that I call `floatquote` with the `float` package. It's not used in the document body, as I can't imagine why one would  make a quotation float. Instead, you  have the  `captionof` command from the  `caption` package. In addition, I included a demonstration of the  `cleveref` package (cross-references that detect the type of structure you're referencing, so you don't have to type its name). 
I also added the  `enumitem` package to use a compact description environment which I find better suited to your case and `babel`to have correct hyphenation in italian. Not knowing what the `\ac` command is supposed to do, I decided quite arbitrarily it was "\relax".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float} 
\newfloat{floatquote}{tbp}{loq}
\floatname{floatquote}{Quote}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font =small, format = hang}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{floatquote}{quote}{quotes}
\Crefname{floatquote}{Quote}{Quotes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian,  english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{floatquote}{tbp}{loq}
\floatname{floatquote}{Quote}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font =small, format = hang}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{floatquote}{quote}{quotes}
\Crefname{floatquote}{Quote}{Quotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\ac{\relax}

\begin{document}
\noindent Some text preceding the quote environment.
\begin{quote}{\selectlanguage{italian}
\begin{description}[noitemsep = 0pt]%style = nextline,
      \item[Percorso del dataset:] Utile in caso di approccio \ac{MC} per individuare il dataset con le epoche random che ha portato allo score migliore;
    \item[Numero totale di epoche:] Utile nel caso 3 per specificare qual'è il numero di epoche che portato allo score migliore;
    \item[Istanti di transizione da un epoca all'altra:] Utile in caso di approccio \ac{MC} per caratterizzare la sequenza di epoche appresa che ha portato allo score migliore;
    \item[Score globale:] Score dell'intera sequenza di strutture;
    \item[Lista dei NaN:] Eventuale lista degli score con valore \ac{NaN};
\end{description}}
\captionof{floatquote}{Output of the Program}\label{quo1}
\end{quote}
In \cref {quo1} we find the output of the program.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before looking at your example, I thought that the caption would be "Quote 1: foo bar" and `cleveref` would have picked the "quote" name for the reference. `;(`

Comment: @T. Verron: I thought first you wanted to have "Figure". A new code example has been uploaded.

Comment: I'm not the OP, who knows, maybe he wants `figure`. But isn't it nicer with "quote"? (Also, it seems that you have a useless label in the body of `\captionof`.)

Comment: OK. I didn't check all the modifications I did.

Comment: My quote is multiline and I need to put the label at the bottom. I have put an example in the first post.

Comment: @Neptune: I modified my answer to use your use. Is that what you want, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

The `figure` environment can still do it for you, it doesn't have to be a *graphic* figure:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{quotation}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{quotation}
    \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: I don't like the figure tag because it isn't a figure.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `quote` environment, but that doesn't float.
You can put text in a figure floating environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is some body text

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \small{This is text.  It's in a figure environment but it's still text}
    \caption{\label{fig_text}Some text that can float as a figure}
\end{figure}

In figure~\ref{fig_text} some text was displayed as a figure.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

So you could if you chose do

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{quote}
        this is some quoted text
    \end{quote}
    \caption{\label{fig_quote}A quote in a figure}
\end{figure}
```

You might need to clarify: Do you want a separate counter (you've got `figure` and `table` already, do you want e.g. `output` as well?)